# class attributes turn from var to val in jar

Tags: scala, class, jar, attributes

I have an `sbt` project with a few classes. One of the classes is `class Relation (var name: String)`. After compiling, I am converting the class files to a jar and using the jar in a different `sbt` project. In this other project, I notice the class definition to be `class Relation (val name: String)`. Not sure why this is happening. Any help in correcting this.

Comment: Isn't using val instead of a var a good practice in Scala? Is there a need for you to use a var instead of a val in the first place?

Comment: @sparkr yes, I need it to be var, as for some operations I want to update the `name` value

Comment: I think the correct way of updating the name is relation.copy(name = "your updated name")

Comment: What do you use to check class definition after compilation? This could be an issue with your IDE or decompiler.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov I am using Intellij IDE. It probably is an issue with IDE where it shows the class attribute as val. But I do not get an error when compiling on the terminal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be not a direct solution to your problem, I would do the following such that you adhere with the principles underpinning Scala!

```
case class Relation(name: String) {
 ....
 ....
}
```

Outside, you create an instance of Relation:

```
val relation = Relation("someName")
```

Now if you want to modify it, use the copy mechanism like:

```
val newRelation = relation.copy(name = "someOtherName")
```

So you control with the copy function which parameters you want to update based on your needs!